# navController.currentDestination + findFragmentById returns null

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigation

I'm trying to find the id for the last fragment navigated to using navController since I'm using the Navigation component instead of fragment managers:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val fragment = this.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(navController.currentDestination!!.id)
    (fragment as IOnBackPressed).onBackPressed().not().let {
        if (it) super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error message when I trigger this code:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.apps.sanctified.IOnBackPressed
    at com.google.apps.sanctified.SanctifiedActivity.onBackPressed(SanctifiedActivity.kt:41)
```

I walked through the code with the debugger, and it appears that navController is finding the correct destination in its backstack and returning the correct id. However, findFragmentById() doesn't seem to have any record of the fragment, and always returns null. The documentation says that this function:

> Finds a fragment that was identified by the given id either when inflated from XML or as the container ID when added in a transaction.

Obviously I'm not using transactions, but it should be updated at inflation. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong there:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DetailFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed to use this:

```
navHost.childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host)
```

Comment: This simple detail saved my time and my day. Thanks!